# how can i speed up copy/paste into a shared workbook using vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that runs on a shared workbook. it copy/pastes from an un-shared workbook into the shared workbook, closes the un-shared workbook, and then does a series of lookups. I find that while shared, the update hangs a bit when it performs the open/copy/paste/close of the un-shared workbook. Is there any way to speed this up?

I have set displayupdate = false and calculations = manual and that did help the lookups but it has not solved the delay on the open/copy/paste/close operation. Any advice?

I know that shared workbooks aren't the best, but my users are keen on it...

Comment: What instructions do you use to copy paste?

Comment: If memory serves me, sharing a workbook forces excel to store versions of itself, check for merge conflicts, etc. Is your macro saving the shared workbook at any time? How often?

Comment: @CRondao i am using opened_ws.range(cells...).copy _ destination:= shared_ws.range(cells...)

Comment: `but it has not solved the delay on the open/copy/paste/close operation. Any advice?` Show us your code

Comment: @Lopsided i am not saving the shared workbook as part of the macro the hang up is occurring when i am copy/pasting from another open wb. when i unshare the destination wb the open/copy/paste/close of the source file is so quick but when i share the destination wb that whole process takes exponentially longer.... oddly the rest of the lookups are just marginally longer in shared mode

Comment: @SiddharthRout i am at work so i can't post the code :(

Comment: Well in that case, seriously I can't suggest you anything which has not been already suggested. It woud be like shooting in the dark...

Comment: thank you all for the feedback! i am thinking it has to do with my .activations to clear prior contents... not sure if there is a way around that (clear contents on a different sheet from the one i am currently on)... i have to switch to that sheet to clear and then switch back

Comment: If you're correct in concluding that the open/copy/paste/close process time while having a shared workbook open is increased exponentially, but otherwise is only increased marginally, then I think the best method for improving performance would be to copy/paste all the un-shared workbooks into another un-shared workbook that will serve as a buffer. Then use your code to open the shared workbook and copy/paste code from the buffer into said shared workbook. This will help if the hangup is occurring in the open/close and not in the copy/paste--which I suspect is the case.

Comment: @Lopsided good suggestion, i will try this... also thinking of hiding a new window of excel and opening the source books there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're correct in concluding that the `open/copy/paste/close` process time while having a shared workbook open is increased exponentially, but otherwise is only increased marginally, then I think the best method for improving performance would be to `copy/paste` all the un-shared workbooks into another un-shared workbook that will serve as a buffer. Then use your code to open the shared workbook and `copy/paste` code from the buffer into said shared workbook.

This will help if the hangup is occurring in the `open/close` and not in the `copy/paste`--which I suspect is the case.

Answer (score 1):

do: `Application.ScreenUpdating = false` I find that helps alot in my work, and i believe is different than displayupdates. Also, make sure that `.activate` is happening as little as possible. each cell or sheet activation is one more processing instruction that often doesnt need to happen. instead, use `offset(rows, Columns)` if possible, or see if you can refer to a sheet and range like `Sheets(1).Range("Cell")`. check for if's / loop's that are coded poorly. replace multiple `if`'s with `elseif`'s if possible.

### edit

I got this from another site -

```
If ActiveWorkbook.MultiUserEditing Then
ActiveWorkbook.ExclusiveAccess
End If
```

I haven't tested it, but maybe you could adapt that to unshare the workbook before doing the copy / paste?

Comment: i have done the screen update as i mentioned in my q. i DID forget to mention that when i am doing the open/copy/paste/close operation i do have to use the destination_ws.activate a couple of times --- this is due to the inability of vba to pass the range properly to clear prior contents ---

Comment: thanks again! i looked at that too, and unfortunately i need to update the shared wb throughout the day with changes while users are in it. seems as if i am stuck... probably the .activations are causing me issues

Comment: ah so it doesnt work while users are in it? that would make sense. the more .activates, the slower, see if you can eliminate a few, use variables to hold values so that you can use .activate only once or twice.

Comment: depending on how long it actually takes, maybe its faster to copy the file down to a local folder, then unshare (as no users are in your local file), then run copy/paste, then copy it back into the shared folder? also, does setting `ActiveWorkbook.ExclusiveAccess` kick users out or error? If it kicks them out I'd send an email saying to save all work as it will kick them out in 2 mins, then run the macro XXDD   -- my apologies by the way as I'm at work also and can't experiment with shared files and such here

Comment: is there a way to clear contents on a sheet that is not the active sheet?

Comment: clear? `sure.. Sheets(number).cells.clear` Also! if you do the copy / paste in 2 steps it works without activating the book! like doing `workbooks(num).Sheets(num).cells.copy` then `ActiveSheet.paste` on a separate line, assuming the sheet you want to paste to is active. Otherwise, you can also do `Sheets(num).cells(1,1).PasteSpecial` to paste in non active sheet. (to paste all sheet contents you need to past in first cell)

Comment: that doesn't work for clearing if you have a specific range not the entire sheet

Comment: i.e. sheets(name).range(cell1, cell2).clearcontents --- it throws up an 1004 error: application-defined or object-defined error. the error goes away once you select the sheet

Comment: tried and tested: exact line of code: `Workbooks("AddressTestData2.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1", "G22").ClearContents` I opened 1 workbook, then opened a second workbook (addressTestData2.xlsx) and then I executed that statement there, in a macro, in the first workbook, with that first book open. also did `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1", "G22").ClearContents`.. executed that from sheet 2 without activating sheet1. You can also try `Range(cell1,cell2).cells.clear` or `Range(cell1,cell2).clear` try a few different ones, they work for me.

Comment: figured it out - the problem is the implicit reference you can't clear range( cell1, cell2).clear executed on a different sheet f/within current sheet because it is actually saying this:
range( activesheet.cell1, activesheet.cell2).clear. when i switched it to this:
range( targetsheet.cell1, targetsheet.cell2).clear it did it for me w/out a problem :)   thank you for the advice!

even by reducing this, the open/copy/paste/close is still taking a long time. i am thinking of doing the other suggestion of combining sheets into one and then importing into the shared sheet. so the pain is less

Comment: must have a diff version of excel cuz like I say, the line worked perfectly for me, but im glad you got it, that woulda bugged the hell out of me XXDD hope the other suggestion works better for speeding things up

Comment: must be! i tried it the way you said it and it just wouldn't do it, kept spitting out the error